# How to keep dialogs on top of main window always on top in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, window

I modified a Qt application to set main window to always be on top using the `setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);`. Now all of the dialogs appear underneath the main window, and the app gets "locked", as you need to close the modal to continue, but the modal is behind the always on top window. I did fix the one dialog by using `dialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);`. Does this mean I have to do the same for every dialog? Or is ther an easier or proper way to set the main window always on top?

Comment: post the code, normally this will not happen if the dialog has the mainWindow as parent...

Comment: can we see the code relating the constructor of the qdialog?

Comment: Ah right yes that is indeed the problem. I have passed the main window as the parent and now it is working as expected. Thanks!